# How to make markdown render html code (real inline YouTube videos) in preview mode? HackMD can't be the only one who knows

Tags: markdown, video-embedding

I am not a coder in this area of coding, I know more about Wordpress (WP) coding than anything else. These other software and their coding systems are just new to me as is the markdown language which I never used until, well, now, but I'm getting used it (seems very simple).

As far as markdown language goes, I first saw HackMD/CodiMD (HMD/CMD) markdown editor and its section on inline "external" sources (e.g. videos, slideshare, etc.). So, I thought that was the markdown standard across the board until I came across other markdown editors without the ability to do inline videos and more.

What I find strange is when I look up how to do markdown for inline YouTube (YT) video, I see a plethora of "It's not possible in markdown." responses followed by "fake it" methods, which does not accomplish what I need. Again, I'm used to embedding videos (WP background) in without an issue: just paste in the video's url link or the embed code and bam that's it and I am not taking off to watch it on YT's actual domain.

So, I need some help trying to figure out how to implement what HMD/CMD was able to successfully do by having inline html (e.g. videos, etc.) rendering in its markdown editor when everyone else keeps saying it's impossible. Again, I am new to messing around with the coding of such software to improve it to my liking, but am definitely willing to learn. I just need to be pointed in the right direction so I can implement it into QOwnNotes (QON) software and then I'll be really satisfied with it.

If you want to know why don't I just use HMD/CMD since it already has what I need: I definitely would have, had it installed on my system and I've tried several times and a couple of different methods to no avail. But now that I have messed around with the UI customization features of QON, which installed on my desktop without a fuss, I was able to actually redesign the default UI of the software, which took a bit of time (I had to research its code and learn something new), but I'm really loving the result. If in the future I can get HMD/CMD to install on my Arch GNU/Linux, then I'll use both.

Meanwhile, any help in the right direction to replicate the inline html rendering for YT videos like HMD/CMD successfully did would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown is a very old and very limited subset of HTML. The original rules can be found [here](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Of note is this:

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its
>   syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of
>   HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to
>   insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert.
>   The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit
>   prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format.
>   Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be
>   conveyed in plain text.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself.

Therefore, the *official* way to embed a video in Markdown is to manually create the HTML (or copy and paste it) and include it in the Markdown document. While it is true that Markdown provides a simple way to include links without authoring HTML, links can be conveyed in plain text, video's can't. And if you point to images, well, it may help to realize that Markdown is older than YouTube, so plain, old-school Markdown doesn't have any knowledge of videos at all.

From one perspective people are correct to say that Markdown does not support video. On the other hand, they are wrong as Markdown supports any raw HTML and it is certainly possible to use raw HTML to embed video into a Markdown document. It all depends on your point of view.

Needless to say, there have been a lot of extensions to Markdown that people have developed over the years. However, none of those extensions have been officially adopted by the creator of Markdown. Some have become widespread and are semi-official in that most implementations support them (although, each has its own unique quirks as there is no central authority for those extensions). But most are one-offs and not transferable from one implementation to the next. That is especially true of video embedding extensions. What is available and how it works is entirely dependent on which implementation of Markdown you are using, how powerful that implementation's extension system is, and how active of a development community has built up around that implementation.

In short, the only sure way to embed video in HTML is to use raw HTML.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I did when launching the software because I thought it was going to be as simple as raw HTML, too, just like in WordPress which is my background, but it just doesn't output in preview mode at all. Nevertheless, I think I have found a couple of markdown-it solutions for video embeds, but I don't know where to put the files in QON. I'll be trying to figure that out.